# Filter columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
 a     a     c     c
 b     a     c     c
 c     a     c     c
 a     b     c     c
 b     b     c     c
 c     b     c     c
```

I have a two lists for col1 and col2

```
list1 = [['a', 'b'], ['a']]
list2 = ['a', 'b']
```

list1 has the values to filter from col1 and list2 has values of col2
Note: The length of two lists will be same.

```
Filter eg : From col1, 'a' and 'b' & col2, 'a'
            From col1, 'a' & col2, 'b'
```

I have tried this

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    df = df.loc[(df['col1'].isin(i)) & (df['col2'] == j)]
```

The output of this results in empty df, But my expected result is

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
 a     a     c     c
 b     a     c     c
 a     b     c     c
```

---

Code for generating the data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col2': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'col3': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'col4': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
})

expected_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    'col2': ['a', 'a', 'b'],
    'col3': ['c', 'c', 'c'],
    'col4': ['c', 'c', 'c']
})

list1 = [['a', 'b'], ['a']]
list2 = ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
df.loc[pd.DataFrame([df.col1.isin(x) & (df.col2 == y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]).any(axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can try with [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to concatenate all the masks :

```
from functools import reduce

m = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [(df["col1"].isin(i) & (df["col2"] == j))
                                for i, j in zip(list1, list2)])
​
out = df.loc[m]
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)
​
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a    a    c    c
1    b    a    c    c
3    a    b    c    c
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `for cond in conditions: df = df.loc[cond]` repeatedly, you're actually applying *all* the conditions (and relation). Your expected output is for when *any* of the conditions hold (or relation) like this:

```
pd.concat(df.loc[df['col1'].isin(i) & df['col2'].eq(j)] 
          for i,j in zip(list1,list2))
```

However, you can use `np.bitwise_or.reduce` to create an `or` mask then slice instead of slice then concat:

```
mask = np.bitwise_or.reduce([df['col1'].isin(i) & df['col2'].eq(j) 
                             for i,j in zip(list1, list2) ])
df.loc[mask]
```

Output

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a    a    c    c
1    b    a    c    c
3    a    b    c    c
```

Another way is merge, but you'll lose original index:

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'col1': list1, 'col2':list2}).explode('col1'),
         on=['col1','col2'], how='inner')
```

Output (note the index difference):

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a    a    c    c
1    b    a    c    c
2    a    b    c    c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based exclusively on list comprehension:

```
df.loc[[z in [(x1, x2) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)
              for x1 in x for x2 in y] 
        for z in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a    a    c    c
1    b    a    c    c
3    a    b    c    c
```